# How To Store Firebase Realtime Database Object In UseState In React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
const [data,setData] = useState({})
firebase.database().ref().on("value", (snapshot) => {
setData(snapshot.val())
})
```

The setData doesn't store any value to the data variable, how can i store the snapshot.val() object in the data

Answer (score 1):

**Update your code**

```
const [data,setData] = useState([])
firebase.database().ref().on("value", snapshot => {
let fetchData= [];
fetchData.push(snapshot.val());
setData({fetchData});
});
```

Console and see whether the data is retrieved or not

Comment: It returns an empty object, Also i have an empty array as the useEffect dependency because i dont want to run it infiniteyl

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve from firebase? You have Set the state as a List ...

Comment: snapshot.val() is an Object, i want to store it in the useState